# Linux software for taking verbal notes?

Tags: software-rec

Is there any software that will listen on the audio inputs of my PC/laptop and will record what I say (in English) into a text file on my computer ?

I need it to be in a format that I can then reasonably easy edit and rework the text.

Ideally the software would not depend on an active internet connection.

I would like to be able to install this on a laptop that uses Lubuntu and a PC which uses KDE Neon.

Thank you

Comment: I linked another question as I found a good enough answer there, I wouldn't say it's an exact fit that question asks for an engine I for an app. I ended up settling for the Chrome app in the answer but I would still like something that can work offline if possible.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation works offline & fully open-source. It's a wrapper for the VOSK-API that I've been using it for some weeks and found it works well.